# How to get rid of white space / margin on right side of the page

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I used some CSS to decrease the height but now the last image gets too much width and it creates a white space/margin on the right side of the page. The first 3 images don't have this issue so I am a bit confused why this happens.

[image]

This is my HTML:

```css
.h-400 {
  height: 400px;
}

img.image {
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid p-0 mt-2">
  <div class="row ">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-12 p-0 h-400">
      <img class="img-fluid image" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/2187605/pexels-photo-2187605.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=3&h=750&w=1260">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-12 p-0 h-400">
      <img class="img-fluid image" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/2187622/pexels-photo-2187622.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260">
    </div>
    <div class="row ">
      <div class="col-md-6 col-12 p-0 h-400">
        <img class="img-fluid image" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/2187966/pexels-photo-2187966.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 col-12 p-0 h-400">
        <img class="img-fluid image" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/2187306/pexels-photo-2187306.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260">
      </div>

      <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
      <div class="row m-0">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-12 p-0 h-400">
          <img class="img-fluid image" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/2187605/pexels-photo-2187605.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=3&h=750&w=1260">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-12 p-0 h-400">
          <img class="img-fluid image" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/2187622/pexels-photo-2187622.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260">
        </div>
        <div class="row m-0">
          <div class="col-md-6 col-12 p-0 h-400">
            <img class="img-fluid image" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/2187966/pexels-photo-2187966.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260">
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6 col-12 p-0 h-400">
            <img class="img-fluid image" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/2187306/pexels-photo-2187306.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Please remove the margin from Row.

Comment: Actually the margin is what I was looking for as well because otherwise I still have the extra margin on the right! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just put it all inside a row div:

```
<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid p-0 mt-2">
  <div class="row ">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-12 p-0 h-400">
      <img class="img-fluid image" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/2187605/pexels-photo-2187605.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=3&h=750&w=1260">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-12 p-0 h-400">
      <img class="img-fluid image" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/2187622/pexels-photo-2187622.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260">
    </div>
  
      <div class="col-md-6 col-12 p-0 h-400">
        <img class="img-fluid image" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/2187966/pexels-photo-2187966.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 col-12 p-0 h-400">
        <img class="img-fluid image" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/2187306/pexels-photo-2187306.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260">
    </div>
    </div>

      <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

> You have 2 `row` classes and there are NO closing tags for those.

```css
.h-400 {
  height: 400px;
}

img.image {
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid p-0 mt-2">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-12 p-0 h-400">
      <img class="img-fluid image" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/2187605/pexels-photo-2187605.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=3&h=750&w=1260">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-12 p-0 h-400">
      <img class="img-fluid image" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/2187622/pexels-photo-2187622.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-12 p-0 h-400">
      <img class="img-fluid image" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/2187966/pexels-photo-2187966.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-12 p-0 h-400">
      <img class="img-fluid image" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/2187306/pexels-photo-2187306.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260">
    </div>
  </div>


  <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: I see! I forgot to add those as well! Thanks for pointing out I need to find a way to check it more clearly because sometimes it gets a bit messy and I don't immediately notice it.

Comment: Actually the code is correct by adding those divs will fix the issue no need to play around with `margin` here, bootstrap will take care of that, you can view my answer in full screen and you will know.

Comment: I saw your answer in full screen and everything is fixed however you can still scroll to the right which results in having extra margin space to the other parts of my website. When I add m-0 to the rows it is fully fixed, however.